# Need Help Pinpointing this warning - Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form and react-redux.

This is the warning I am getting.

[image]

You will notice that is points to 3 places in my code CreateNewOrderForm.jsx:39, NewOrderFormFour.jsx:65, and NewOrderFormFour.jsx:122.

I need another pair eyes to look at it.

CreateNewOrderForm.jsx:39:

```
toggleDialog = (id) => {
    const { dialog, openDialogFunction, closeDialogFunction } = this.props;
    if (dialog.show && (dialog.id === 'confirmOrderDialog' || 'confirmOrderDialog')) {
      closeDialogFunction(id);
    }
    else {
      openDialogFunction(id, 1);
    }
  }
```

NewOrderFormFour.jsx:65:

```
openConfirmationDialog = () => {
  const { openDialogFunction } = this.props;
  openDialogFunction('confirmOrderDialog');
}
```

NewOrderFormFour.jsx:122:

```
<Form
 id="createOrder"
 onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.openConfirmationDialog()) }
>
```

Do I need to call the `this.openConfirmationDialog` method in the handleSubmit?

Or put it in a callback?

Struggled to pinpoint the error since i get over 1000 of them.

What could i change to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use arrow funcion in submit `onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(this.openConfirmationDialog()) }`. In your variant you call this function when component rendering.

Comment: i will give that a try. it is just interesting i did not need to dow that on the prior 3 pages. or at least the first two. Still, i will try it.

Comment: Ok that worked. Why did it work? lol. especially when i don't always have to do that?

Comment: It worked before, because you call function without arguments, right?

Comment: yeah i believe so.